# Cropping an image in flutter

Tags: flutter, image, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-image

So I've been trying really hard to crop an image according to my needs in flutter.

Problem statement:
I have a screen and in that screen I show a frame while the device camera is run on the background. Now, what I want is that whenever the user clicks a photo, only the area of that image inside the frame should be kept and rest should be cropped.

What I have done so far?

- Added a package **image 3.1.3**
- Wrote code to fetch x,y coordinates of my frame.
- Using the calculated x,y coordinates and copyCrop method from the Image package to crop the clicked image.

Now the problem is that I do not know how copyCrop works and the code right now does not give me the expected results.

```
final GlobalKey _key = GlobalKey();
void _getOffset(GlobalKey key) {
    RenderBox? box = key.currentContext?.findRenderObject() as RenderBox?;
    Offset? position = box?.localToGlobal(Offset.zero);
    if (position != null) {
      setState(() {
        _x = position.dx;
        _y = position.dy;
      });
    }
  }
```

I assign this _key to my Image.file(srcToFrameImage) and the function above yields 10, 289.125

Here 10 is the offset from x and 289.125 is the offset from y. I used this [tutorial](https://www.kindacode.com/article/flutter-finding-x-and-y-coordinates-of-a-widget-at-runtime/) for the same.

Code to crop my image using the Image package:

```
var bytes = await File(pictureFile!.path).readAsBytes();
img.Image src = img.decodeImage(bytes)!;
img.Image destImage = img.copyCrop(
   src, _x!.toInt(), _y!.toInt(), src.width, src.height);
var jpg = img.encodeJpg(destImage);
await File(pictureFile!.path).writeAsBytes(jpg);
bloc.addFrontImage(File(pictureFile!.path));
```

Now, can anyone tell me how i can do this effectively? Right now, it does crop my image but not as I want it to be. It would be really great if someone could tell me how does copyCrop work and what is the meaning of all these different parameters that we pass into it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Edit:
[image: Frame Image]

Now, as you can see, i only want the image between this frame to be kept after being captured and rest to be cropped off.

Comment: maybe add a picture of what you are trying to achieve

Comment: If you are using a `RepaintBoundary` to output a screenshot, you can decide where to put the widget, and it'll only capture what's inside that widget. I'm just not sure if native views (the camera feed) can be captured using repaint boundary, if it can, you won't need cropping.